# Whats ASKS Security Software and Device Protection Manager?

Tags: samsung, default-applications

My phone updated and when i check about device i got something i never know about that ASKS Security Software thing and a new appication named Device Protection Manager with no accessable interface

[image: DEVICE PROTECTION MANAGER] [image: ASKS]

So what are these and what does it do?
And is it recommended to remove these features because so far i think its useless

Answer (score 1):

The phrase 'Device Protection Manager' is an uncommon name for this software. Usually it is truncated to 'device protection'.  I found a link that may help you.

https://www.greenbot.com/article/2904397/everything-you-need-to-know-about-device-protection-in-android-51.html

Basically, it is anti-theft software, plus...  You could have 3rd party software that is doing the same thing, so you may want to scour your device for such and eliminate all but one. Choose one that doesn't drain your battery so much.